# Weird MacOS Chrome issue with checkboxes and focus

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

When I programmatically focus on a checkbox input (`<input type="checkbox" id="onscreen-kb" name="onscreen-kb">`) by calling the element's `focus()` method, it does not send out a focus event to indicate that it has gained focus, nor does it show a focus outline.

The element is, however, actually in focus — at least at some level. `document.activeElement` is equal to element. The space bar toggles it on and off.

Tabbing to the checkbox via the Tab key, rather than programmatically focusing, does cause the focus outline to appear, but the checkbox still doesn't emit a focus event when it gains focus.

I've only tried this on MacOS so far. The bug is only happening in Chrome. Firefox and Safari don't have the problem. Type `text` input fields both show focus outlines and emit focus events via programmatic focusing.

When I google this topic all I find is a lot of stuff from people who don't like the focus outlines on checkboxes, and who want to hide them. That's not my issue here. What I'm trying to do is make an onscreen keyboard to perform tabbing just like a real keyboard, for when my app is run in kiosk mode.

Does anyone know a way to make these checkboxes behave better? To enforce the idea that they're supposed to emit focus events when `input.addEventListener('focus'...)` has been performed?

Update: Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```js
function focused(e) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += (this.id + " focused") + "<br>";
}

$("#onscreen-kb").on("focus", focused);
$("#onscreen-kb2").on("focus", focused);

function focus1() {
  document.getElementById("onscreen-kb").focus();
}

function focus2() {
  document.getElementById("onscreen-kb2").focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="onscreen-kb" name="onscreen-kb">
<input type="checkbox" id="onscreen-kb2" name="onscreen-kb"><br>
<button onclick="focus1()">focus 1</button>
<button onclick="focus2()">focus 2</button>
<br>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Comment: In general, events are only sent for externally-caused actions, not actions done by JavaScript.

Comment: Tabbing between checkboxes sends out a focus event for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wktpuqr3/4/

Comment: @Barmar, if that's the case, why do the text input fields reliably emit focus events on all of these browsers, and the checkboxes do so on two out of three?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar, I'll try. The original code is fairly complex, so pulling out a sample version with take a bit of time.

Comment: See my jsfiddle for a simple example

Comment: I added a simple example, but it the example, the problem doesn't happen. Aaarggghhh.

Comment: That suggests that there's something in your real code that's interfering. Maybe another event listener that calls `event.stopPropagation()`.